# Как правильно "объединить" изображение и гиперссылку

Tags: html, asp.net, веб-программирование

У меня есть изображение и есть ссылка под ним.

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы можно было кликать и по изображению, и по ссылке. В результате клика пользователь переходит по одной и той же ссылке.

Как это правильно сделать?

1. "Обернуть" вокруг изображения ссылку.
2. Обернуть изображение и текст под ним как одну ссылку.

Какой вариант правильный? Пишу на visual studio 2010, сайт asp.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подпись к картинке не обязана являться ссылкой. Я бы сделал изображение и ссылку в отдельных тегах:

```
<p>
    <a href="lorem.html">
        <img src="images/girl.png" width="189" height="255" alt="lorem">
    </a>
    <a href="lorem.html">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</a>
</p>
```

Мне так идеологически больше нравится. Но в принципе оба варианта правильны.

Comment: А это не отразится на SEO, если будут подряд две ссылки ?

Comment: Да не должно. Это же не пятьдесят одинаковых предложений в скрытом диве =)